# How to count up hours and minutes in total with split

Tags: python, split

```
print("Please fill in the activity in hours")
Ac1 = input("School: ").split()
for School in Ac1:
     hour, min = [(i) for i in School.split(":")]

Ac2 = input("Work: ").split()
for Work in Ac2:
     hour, min = [(i) for i in Work.split(":")]

Ac3 = input("Sports: ").split()
for Sports in Ac3:
     hour, min = [(i) for i in Sports.split(":")]

Total = (Ac1 + Ac2 +Ac3)
print(Total)
```

input i gave are not counting up instead they stick on each other.

Comment: Please provide a sample input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you've provided has several quite big problems, but from what I understand, what you want is something like this:

```
print("Please fill in the activity in hours")
hours = 0
minutes = 0

schools = input("School: ").split()
for school in schools:
    parts = school.split(":")
    hours += int(parts[0])
    minutes += int(parts[1])

works = input("Work: ").split()
for work in works:
    parts = work.split(":")
    hours += int(parts[0])
    minutes += int(parts[1])

sports = input("Sports: ").split()
for sport in sports:
    parts = sport.split(":")
    hours += int(parts[0])
    minutes += int(parts[1])

hours += int(minutes / 60)
minutes = minutes % 60
print("Total: {}:{}".format(hours, minutes))
```

Although note that this is a very simple example and lacks a couple of important features, like input validation. But again, your question is not at all clear so I just fixed your own sample code.

Comment: If this answers your question, please check it as the correct answer (using the check mark on the left), so other people can rely on it

Answer (score 0):

As Amir has already given the correct answer, I thought I would throw in another way of getting the same answer with the help of a dictionary...

```
hours = 0

print("Please fill in the activity in hours")

categories = {'School': (),
              'Work': (),
              'Sports': ()
              }

for k, v in categories.items():
    time = input(f'{k}:').split(":")
    categories[k] = (int(time[0]), int(time[1]))

for v in categories.values():
    hours += v[0] + (v[1] / 60)

mins = (hours - int(hours)) * 60

print(f'{int(hours)}:{int(mins)}')
```

Comment: Question Kamal
How can I deduct the total hours and minutes by 24h and 8h of sleep? for example the total output of hours are 5,  i want to deduct that from 24h and 8h. Then the output should be 24-8-5 = 11